# jQuery ajax returns [object Error]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, rest

I have a HTML page that calls an API, but every time I try to run I keep getting an `[object Error]`.

Here is my code:

```
jQuery.support.cors = true;
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://xxxx:8440/ora/authenticationService/authentication/signIn",
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{'requestParameters':{'username':'xxxx', 'password':'xxxx'}}",
    success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
        alert('exito!');
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
        alert("Falla : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Any ideas about this error?

Comment: where in this code does the error occur?

Comment: The alert() command simply calls toString() on whatever is passed to it, so you're seeing the string representation of the error object. Try using `console.log(errorThrown)` instead of `alert(errorTHrown)`, you'll be able to see a lot more info in the console than you will through an alert prompt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Already found a solution for my project but can not do it with JQuery, has to do with .NET

Here's a snippet of the code if it helps someone:

```
    WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://xxxxxx/ora/authenticationService/authentication/signIn");
    request.Method = "POST";

    string postData = "{\"requestParameters\":{\"username\" : \"xxxx\", \"password\":\"xxxx\"}}";
    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);

    request.ContentType = "application/json";
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

    System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback valor = new System.Net.Security.RemoteCertificateValidationCallback(ValidateServerCertificate);
    ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = valor;

    Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
    dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
    dataStream.Close();

    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
    dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

    string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

    HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;
    NameValueCollection headerList = response.Headers;  

    HttpContext.Current.Session["JSESSIONID"] = headerList.Get("Set-Cookie");


    reader.Close();
    dataStream.Close();
    response.Close();
```

Thanks to all!

Answer (score 0):

The most likely explanation is that the server is throwing an error when you tell it you are sending JSON but your JSON is not valid.

You can't use `'` to delimit strings in JSON.

Don't try to write JSON by hand, construct a JavaScript object and then use a JSON serialisation library.

```
data: JSON.stringify({requestParameters:{username:'xxxx', password:'xxxx'}),
```

Comment: Do it in that way, but now give me nothing (nor success or failure).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that `jQuery.support.cors = true;` is only used to check if the browser supports cors, not set it.

Perhaps try using JSONP instead of JSON. JSONP was specifically designed for cross domain data requests.

Comment: If remove that line, the error given is "No Transport", i've read about that error and the answer give it is to put that line to correct the error.